# Concatenate 2 Bibtex files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Is it possible to concatenate two BibTeX `.bib`-files? E.g. to write:

```
\include{child.bib}
```

into my `parent.bib`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to concatenate BibTeX files from different folders and keep valid links for referenced files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63078/5764)

Comment: Why can't you just say `\bibliography{child1,child2}` in your document?